# how to send php Get parameters to an iFrame?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

I have multiple items on a php page, to edit each item, i want to send the title of the button as a parameter to an iFrame (popup), how can i do this ?

i have a code like this :

```html
<button class="btn_edit ui-button-text-only" title="245" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Edit this item</span></button>

<button class="btn_edit ui-button-text-only" title="246" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Edit this item</span></button>

<button class="btn_edit ui-button-text-only" title="247" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Edit this item</span></button>

<button class="btn_edit ui-button-text-only" title="248" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Edit this item</span></button>

<button class="btn_edit ui-button-text-only" title="249" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Edit this item</span></button>
```

`itemID` = the title variable.

to get similar result : `iframe src="index.php?type=1296727025&itemID.`

I tried to `append()` but didn't work,

```html
$dialog_edit.append($("<iframe class='no-border full-width-height' />").attr("src", "index.php?type=1296727025&tx_productmanager_pi1="+productID+"&no_cache=1"));
$dialog_edit.dialog('open');
```

Does any one has an idea ?

Comment: what's your other code for `append()`?

Comment: Mi append code is this :
$('.btn_edit_product').click(function() {
 var productID = $(this).attr('title');

 $dialog_edit.append($("<iframe class='no-border full-width-height' />").attr("src", "index.php?type=1296727025&tx_productmanager_pi1[productID]="+productID+"&no_cache=1"));
 alert (productID); // This alert show me the productID
 $dialog_edit.dialog('open');
 return false;
});

Answer (score 1):

```js
        
         
    
           $(document).ready(function(){
    
           $('.my-button').click(function() {
    
            var title = $(this).attr("title");
            var src =  "index.php?type=1296727025&itemID=" + title;
             console.log(src);
            $("#my-div").html("<iframe src='" + src + "' width='100%' height='600'></iframe>");
    
          });
    
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn_edit ui-button-text-only my-button" title="245" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
  <span class="ui-button-text">Edit this item</span>
</button>
<button class="btn_edit ui-button-text-only my-button" title="242" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
  <span class="ui-button-text">Edit this item</span>
</button>
 <div id="my-div">
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a demo on my local and it is working fine. Do check below code. As abc.php is not real path or file, it will not show actual result here.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#button').click(function() {
    $("#myIframe").html('<iframe id="myIframe" src="abc.php?id=12" width=500 height=500></iframe>');
    var Isrc = $("#myIframe").attr('src');
    Isrc = Isrc;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="button">Click Me</button>
  <div id="myIframe">
  </div>
```